# React Lazy Load useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, асинхронность, react-hook, lazyloading

У меня проблема с получением **clientWidth** из **useEffect**.

Есть **lazyLoad** который загружает страничку с пользователями.

```
import { Suspense, lazy } from 'react';

const UsersContainer = lazy(() => import('./users/users-container'));

const Index = (props) => {
    return (
        <Suspense fallback={<div id={'loading'}/>}>
            <UsersContainer/>
        </Suspense>
    )
}

export default Index;
```

В **UsersContainer** есть дочерняя компонента **dataTooltip**, которая отображает полное имя User если оно не влазит в блок.

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from 'react';

import '../common.scss';

const DataTooltip = ({title, ...props}) => {
    let ref = useRef();

    useEffect(() => {
        if (ref.current.scrollWidth > ref.current.clientWidth) {
            ref.current.setAttribute('data-tooltip', title)
        }
    });

    return (
        <div ref={ref} className={'tooltip'}>
            {
                React.cloneElement(props.children, {ref: ref})
            }
        </div>
    )
}

export default DataTooltip;
```

В чем же проблема?

После того как **UsersContainer** загрузился и отрисовался в **DOM**, у него *'display: none'* и в этот же момент асинхронно срабатывает **useEffect** в **DataTooltip**.

В итоге **DataTooltip** говорит что *clientWidth = 0*, из-за того что у родителя 'display: none'.

Как сделать так что бы **useEffect** срабатывал после того как **lazyLoad** убрал *'display: none'*.

PS: useLayoutEffect работает так же, *clientWidth = 0*

---

**Решил проблему так:**

```
<Suspense fallback={<div id={'loading'}/>}>
   <Main/>
   <Acquaintance/>
   <UsersContainer/>
   <RegisterContainer/>
</Suspense>
```

**должно быть**

```
<Suspense fallback={<div id={'loading'}/>}>
    <Main/>
</Suspense> 
            
<Suspense fallback={<div id={'loading'}/>}>
    <Acquaintance/> 
</Suspense>
            
<Suspense fallback={<div id={'loading'}/>}>
    <UsersContainer/>
</Suspense>
            
<Suspense fallback={<div id={'loading'}/>}>
    <RegisterContainer/>
</Suspense>
```

Comment: У вас есть эта проблема, когда вы не используете `lazy` и `Suspense`?

Comment: Решил проблему, выше отредактировал.

Comment: Я не совсем понимаю как это работает, и не смогу объяснить

Comment: Без проблем. Я постараюсь, если у меня будет время.